# How to run processes in the background and override standard streams

Tags: python, linux, process, stream, stdin

I want to write a python script which should create a process **in the background**, redirect its **stdin**, **stdout** and **stderr** for communication with that process (this executable is my program) to a **separate** virtual streams.

I need to run several instances of my program at once from python script and i need a proper solution to receive/send messages to their overriden streams. I have no experience on sub/process/streams in python, i am looking for a diamong code sample, thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["mycmd", "--somearg"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Does p.communicate() returns array? And how do i redirect stdin?

Comment: If you pass stdin=PIPE, the communicate call will write to the process' stdin descriptor.

Comment: Found this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate and https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886654/difference-between-communicate-and-stdin-write-stdout-read-or-stderr-read and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate